# How many non-engineered species are in the Alien/Predator universe?

Tags: alien-franchise, predator-series

First of all I'm not particular confident of what is considered canon in this universe. As far as I know all the films are canon but I'm unsure about video games and comic books.

The framing of my question I would think would exclude Humans [and all Earth species], Xenomorphs (all stages), and the wacky creatures from Prometheus and Resurrection. So yes, lets say they don't count.

I recall there are collections of bones/trophies seen in the Predator ships but there should be enough of a resemblance to have an idea of what the overall creature looked like.

That said are there just Engineers and Predators (including Super Predators)? There seems to be zero link between these two [in regard to Predators being engineered by Engineers].

Comment: I edited out the tag [tag:prometheus], since this question is not *about* the  film *Prometheus* or events that occur therein, but about the general universe to which *Prometheus* belongs.

Comment: Lots; http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/LV-1201_bug